# Quartz 2.0 not able to insert data into tables

Tags: oracle, quartz-scheduler

I just configured my quartz with oracle job store. But, when i run jobs ..the jobs were running but they were not getting inserted into the tables ?

Is there any other way for configuring this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have problems with the configuration file. The jobs must be stored in RAM.

Comment: gemr1423 is very likely correct.  If your properties file is not found in the classpath and you simply use getScheduler() then you'll get one what uses RAMJobStore.